# Reinstalling Ubuntu and removing Windows on the same SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

Here's my situation:

- I have Windows 8.1 installed on my SSD
- I have Ubuntu installed on my HDD
- I have the boot loaders for both installed on my SSD

I want to remove Windows, and reinstall Ubuntu onto my SSD. How can I do this cleanly, without messing anything up?

Comment: So you want to put Ubuntu onto ssd. What will be on the hdd ?

Comment: @Serg I will leave it for storage, or probably install Windows on it since I use Ubuntu as my primary OS now

Comment: In that case, I suggest you physically disconnect that HDD, run installation with SSD connected only. Choose to erase disk and reinstall OS . This will be the most harmless and easiest way. Once you want to set up that HDD, you can add its UUID into `/etc/fstab` file, so that it's mounted each time you boot. Or mount it manually every time you need it.

Comment: Let me know if you want that as an actual answer, I'll post. The above are just comments

Comment: @Serg yes please that would be great. Why do you need to disconnect the HDD?

Comment: That way , you don't have to figure out which disk to select. When you go to "Something else" option in the installer,  you will see disks listed as /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. Now, if it says , ntfs next to /dev/sda1 that is your windows partition.  Linux is ext4 . At that point you can delete ntfs partition and create new ext4. But why do guessing,  if you can make sure it's operating on just one disk right off the bat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing *anything drastic*, [always make a back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and then go on to *the easiest* and safe way to do this is using `os-uninstaller`.

1. Boot to Ubuntu from a LiveCD/DVD/USB
2. Open a terminal by pressing  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy paste:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
   ```
3. Open `os-uninstaller` from the dash and you'll get this window:

   [image]

   choose the OS you want to remove. You'll be asked to confirm, click <kbd>OK</kbd> and wait tell it finishes removing.

Comment: are  you sure this will work? I don't want anything to mess up

Comment: Yes this will work. Keep the live-usb with u for in case grub missed you will be able to use boot repair to fix it. But that won't happen.

Comment: @mightyspaj: verified...

Comment: Okay thanks this works. You should also mention that when you reinstall Ubuntu, that you should erase your drives.

Answer (score 1):

Boot up your system with the ubuntu bootable disk or USB and choose the manual partitioning. Delete the windows partition and reinstall with the new OS on your  HDD or SSD.